# Getting EF Core 2 Scaffolding to use plurialization correctly

Tags: ef-core-2.0

New to EF Core 2, used EF 6.x with Database first.

I was hoping that when I scaffolded a database with tables that had pleural names (ie Users) the class created for each table would be singular (ie User). Instead, I get something like public virtual DbSet Users  Users { get; set;}. What I was hoping for was public virtual DbSet User  Users { get; set;}.

Is there a switch on the Package Manager Console line that will allow me to do this or must I edit after scaffolding?

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core doesn't include pluralization, but it can be added as [a design-time service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/services) (`IPluralizer`).

The [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) include an implementation.

If you're using EF Core 2.1.0-preview2-final, you can use [my package](http://www.bricelam.net/2018/03/02/efcore-pluralization.html):

```
Install-Package Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer -Version 1.0.0-rc2
Scaffold-DbContext ...
```